# Numpy array from cStringIO object and avoiding copies

Tags: python, numpy, stringio

This to understand things better. It is not an actual problem that I need to fix. A `cstringIO` object is supposed to emulate a string, file and also an iterator over the lines. Does it also emulate a buffer ? In anycase ideally one should be able to construct a numpy array as follows

```
import numpy as np
import cstringIO

c = cStringIO.StringIO('\x01\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00')

#Trying the iterartor abstraction
b = np.fromiter(c,int)
# The above fails with: ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

#Trying the file abstraction
b = np.fromfile(c,int)
# The above fails with: IOError: first argument must be an open file

#Trying the sequence abstraction
b = np.array(c, int)
# The above fails with: TypeError: long() argument must be a string or a number 

#Trying the string abstraction
b = np.fromstring(c)
#The above fails with: TypeError: argument 1 must be string or read-only buffer

b = np.fromstring(c.getvalue(), int)  # does work
```

My question is why does it behave this way.

The practical problem where this came up is the following: I have a iterator which yields a tuple. I am interested in making a numpy array from one of the components of the tuple with as little copying and duplication as possible. My first cut was to keep writing the interesting components of the yielded tuple into a StringIO object and then use its memory buffer for the array. I can of course use `getvalue()` but will create and return a copy. What would be a good way to avoid the extra copying.

Comment: It appears there is a ticket out for this http://projects.scipy.org/numpy/ticket/1634 Dont know whether that means this is considered a bug or not. I would still be interested in knowing how to avoid the copying.

Comment: the failure symptom for case 1 has changed: ValueError: invalid literal for long() with base 10: '\x01'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem seems to be that numpy doesn't like being given characters instead of numbers. Remember, in Python, single characters and strings have the same type — numpy must have some type detection going on under the hood, and takes `'\x01'` to be a nested sequence.

The other problem is that a `cStringIO` iterates over its lines, not its characters.

Something like the following iterator should get around both of these problems:

```
def chariter(filelike):
    octet = filelike.read(1)
    while octet:
        yield ord(octet)
        octet = filelike.read(1)
```

Use it like so (note the seek!):

```
c.seek(0)
b = np.fromiter(chariter(c), int)
```

Comment: Nice. Is there a way to avoid the looping in Python. As you correctly pointed out cStringIO objects iterate over lines, but it does so in C context. Is there a Python object that would iterate over characters of a filelike object that I can fill or iterate over in C context.

Comment: @san - Re. the looping: I can't think of a way around it. I had a look at some of the utils in `itertools`, but couldn't see any way to adapt them. And I don't think there's a character-based iterator, either — I've needed one in the past, and just ended up writing something like this. (I could be wrong, so if there is, I'd like to know!)

Comment: @san - I didn't think to ask — are you familiar with the `yield` notation? If you're not, the "function" I wrote up there is actually not a continually looping function, but a generator that retains state between calls to `next()`.

Comment: yeah I know generators. but I think it still incurs an overhead similar to looping. For the actual problem I was quite surprised that using an `a = array.array('d')` and running `map(a.extend(), iterator)` worked as well as it did.

Answer (score 2):

As `cStringIO` does not implement the buffer interface, if its `getvalue` returns a copy of the data, then there is no way to get its data without copying.

If `getvalue` returns the buffer as a string without making a copy, `numpy.frombuffer(x.getvalue(), dtype='S1')` will give a (read-only) numpy array referring to the string, without an additional copy.

---

The reason why `np.fromiter(c, int)` and `np.array(c, int)` do not work is that `cStringIO`, when iterated, returns a line at a time, similarly as files:

```
>>> list(iter(c))
['\x01\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00']
```

Such a long string cannot be converted to a single integer.

```
***
```

It's best not to worry too much about making copies unless it really turns out to be a problem. The reason is that the extra overhead in e.g. using a generator and passing it to `numpy.fromiter` may be actually larger than what is involved in constructing a list, and then passing that to `numpy.array` --- making the copies may be cheap compared to Python runtime overhead.

However, if the issue is with memory, then one solution is to put the items directly into the final Numpy array. If you know the size beforehand, you can pre-allocate it. If the size is unknown, you can use the `.resize()` method in the array to grow it as needed.